# how to create one click setup for .net project to install several files and dlls

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

my project requies multiple things to be installed on other computer,
like
1. .net framework 4.0
2. visual C++ libraries
3. sqlite dll to be copied to GAC
4. one sample file, to be copied to application directory
5. one folder and its subfiles to be copied to my document
6. running the setup of actual project
etc etc

how can I make one click setup which does all these things, so that user dont have to do anything extra.

Answer (score 0):

i show you the way , crossing is by you

install "install shield " software ( a program for making setup ) 
Make a new project and use prerequisites(tools > Build prerequisites ) and define the programs that you need to be installed before your main setup

hope to be useful ...